# Copy file from source directory tree to new location using source folder as name

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a directory of files and folders such as:

```
\Parent
|-\Child
||-\Test
|||-\Content
|||-targetfile.ext.out
|-\AnotherChild
||-anothertargetfile.ext.out
```

I want to copy any file that has the .ext.out to another directory, but rename it with the directory structure.

EG: targetfile.ext.out would be copied to a defined directory with the name "ParentChildTestContent.ext.out" and "anothertargetfile.ext.out" would be copied to that same defined directory as "AnotherChild.ext.out".  The .out can be stripped for simplicity of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as far as your folder structure is not more than 22 levels deep.

As you have not indicated if the "source" folder is the root of the drive, as assuming you need the final name only contain the folders from "source" and below, it uses `pushd` and `xcopy` to retrieve a relative path to the required files, splitting the retrieved list on the backslashes and joining the parts into the final file name.

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "source=d:\temp\k"
    set "target=c:\somewhere"

    pushd "%source%"
    for /d %%w in ("."
    ) do for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%x in ('xcopy /l /s "*.txt" "%temp%"'
    ) do for /f "tokens=1-22 delims=\" %%a in ("%%~y"
    ) do echo copy /y "%source%\%%~y" "%target%\%%~nxw%%a%%b%%c%%d%%e%%f%%g%%h%%i%%j%%k%%l%%m%%n%%o%%p%%q%%r%%s%%t%%u%%v"
    popd
```

The script only echoes the required `copy` commands to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` command.

Comment: Thanks a ton.  This did exactly what I was hoping for after some minor tweaks.

I modified the last line to use xcopy and put an "*" at the end of the target to assume file and everything worked great.

Answer (score 0):

I would use DIR /S /B to explore the directory and its sub-folders, and get an easily usable result:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set "DEST=.\output"

REM Get complete absolute path for every interesting file
for /f %%a in ('dir /S /B .\Parent\*txt') do (
    REM Process name as desired
    set "newName=%%a"
    set "newName=!newName:\=_!"
    set "newName=!newName:*Parent_=!"

    copy %%a %DEST%\!newName!
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This script should be robust - it uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

Change `d:\\target` to the folder you need - the double `\` is necessary.
Also change `\parent`

The script creates a batch file called `temp.bat.txt` to to the copying and you can examine it in notepad before using it.

```
@echo off
dir /b /s /a-d "\parent\*.ext.out" |repl "..(.*)\\(.*)\\.*\.(.*\..*)" "copy \q$&\q \qd:\\target\\$2.$3\q" x >temp.bat.txt
```